# Precision of delay

Tags: android, delay

I have a problem with this code used for Android (Java)

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    // Your code goes here...
}
}, 500);
```

If the delay is about 500ms then the program seems to repeat the task at 0.5s, but if I change to less than 100ms or even less it does not follow any more. I test the brightness change and for a while it can repeat the change of brightness at that rate, but then slow down and come back to normal flash rate again. It seems unstable. Do you have any code that give exact delay regardless of the load of the phone's CPU.

Many thanks

Comment: `postDelayed`  promises only that the delay will be _at least_ the posted amount.  The actual delay depends on details of thread scheduling including stuff you have no way to affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do something more precise if you use a CountDownTimer which has a periodic tick. Essentially you set it to count down for a period which can be hours if need be, and there are two methods one method is called on each tick, and the other at the end of the timer at which point you could start another one. Anyway you could set the tick to be very fast, and then only kick off the code at the delay point by check the actual time difference in the click. I think thats about the best you could do. Essentially inside the tick you would issue a signal if the right amout of time had actually passed. That signal would either kick off the thread or release something the already running thread was waiting on.  What is the value of the CountDownTimer, I guess its just that you can do a very frequent polling, and elapsed time check. Although its not guaranteed, the time between the ticks you can set it to a high frequency and check/poll very frequently.  This could lead to a smooth performance not unlike a realtime system. Its more likely to be accurate because its just issuing a signal and not taking up the resources of threading just to issue the signal.  You might also try an IntentService to perform the tasks and just call startService(intentToIntentService) each call.  See if the threading works better inside a service like IntentService which does queue them up I believe.

```
 Date startDate = new Date();
 long startTime = startDate.getTime();
 // Tick called every 10th of a second.  OnFinish called at Signal.
 CountDownTimer ctDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 100) {
 long startIntervalTime=startTime;
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     Date now = new Date();
     long nowTime = now.getTime();
     if ((startIntervalTime - nowTime) > 100)
     {
        issueSignal();
        intervalStartTime=nowTime;
     }
     now=null;
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     Log.d("MyClass", "Done")  // Maybe start out.
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guide. I am quite new to Android to be honest so if you could let me have a reference or similar code that do the same thing so I could try to adopt.

Comment: I would start experimenting with count down timer. issueSignal() would either do the operation itself or somehow kick off the thread or call the intent service with startService(intent).

Comment: Might need to use absolute values in comparision and experiment with the numbers or have a stricter bound.  Keep in mind logging takes some time too but it is good for debugging along the way to see what values you are getting. Might do Log.i() instead so you can see it w/o debug mode.

Comment: While `CountDownTimer` is certainly easier to use it is essentially the same as posting a delayed runnable. If you look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java) it even uses the same `Message.sendDelayed` mechanism

Comment: The subtle difference is that inside onTick() you are NOT running the thread code. You are issuing a signal.  And you may not issue it on every tick specified but only after checking conditions.  The difference is subtle but important.  Essentially you are running continuous condition polling. Thats very different than running the code at each polling interval.

Comment: Here you have the options to kick off or not kick off something based on your observation of conditions which include the estimated elapsed time.

Comment: The success really depends on what you are doing in the code and the how signal is implemented. While you don't have real-time you can simulate this capability.

Comment: Posting a `Runnable` does not execute in a new thread. It's enqueueing a special `Message` in the main thread `Looper` which calls the appropriate `handleMessage` method of a `Handler` or directly calls the `run` method in case of a `Runnable`. No new `Thread` involved. See [Handler.dispatchMessage(Message)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Handler.java#Handler.dispatchMessage%28android.os.Message%29) source, especially the `handleCallback` method which calls `message.callback.run()` where `callback` is the `Runnable`

Comment: I know that. My point is that the block of code which is called run(){} is not executed at each interval point in this Thead or another Thead.  Instead you are checking as frequently as possible the status (which is NOT done with the post message because the operation is never going to be given this level of priority) It is however an option to issue an AsyncTask etc at these points if you did want to run it outside the UI Thread.

Comment: Many thanks Code Droid. I will try that. Much appreciate your time.

Answer (score 5):

Not from Java, no; stock Java isn't a real-time system.

Timing precision is subject to the whims of the JVM *and* the OS's scheduler. You may be able to get incrementally more precise, but there's no guarantee of the kind of precision you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, but is there any way to force Android respect the timing?

Comment: @notebook Not from Java, no; stock Java isn't a real-time system. Nor is Linux.

Comment: A comment regarding the downvote would be appreciated; this is the answer.

Comment: @CodeDroid You missed my point; there's no good reason to *downvote* this answer, since ultimately, it's the answer--you simply cannot guarantee timing in Java (or Linux) unless you have real-time extensions. Whether or not another answer comes incrementally closer, or says the same thing, doesn't have anything to do with asking for a downvote explanation. I don't even care if the accepted answer is completely wrong--accepting an answer only means the OP thought it was the most helpful. I'm asking why there was a downvote.